# Payment with PayPal but it redirect to cart page instead of PayPal, How can i solve this?

Tags: paypal

Redirects to cart page and it will not shows any error. While checking log it shows me below log

```
[url] => https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp

    [SetExpressCheckout] => Array
        (
            [PAYMENTACTION] => Authorization
            [AMT] => 557.48
            [CURRENCYCODE] => GBP
            [RETURNURL] => 
            [CANCELURL] => 
            [INVNUM] => 100000070
            [SOLUTIONTYPE] => Mark
            [GIROPAYCANCELURL] => 
            [GIROPAYSUCCESSURL] =>
            [BANKTXNPENDINGURL] => 
            [LOCALECODE] => en_GB
            [ITEMAMT] => 557.48
            [TAXAMT] => 0.00
            [SHIPPINGAMT] => 0.00
            [L_NUMBER0] => BC220[¬!~U
            [L_NAME0] => WEETABIX A PACK *
            [L_QTY0] => 1
            [L_AMT0] => 38.74
            [L_NUMBER1] => BC220[¬!~I
            [L_NAME1] => WEETABIX A PACK *
            [L_QTY1] => 1
            [L_AMT1] => 38.74
            [L_NUMBER2] => BA040   CR[¬!~U
            [L_NAME2] => BACON FARMHOUSE STREAKY
            [L_QTY2] => 15
            [L_AMT2] => 16.00
            [L_NUMBER3] => BA040   CR[¬!~I
            [L_NAME3] => BACON FARMHOUSE STREAKY
            [L_QTY3] => 15
            [L_AMT3] => 16.00
            [BUSINESS] => company
            [NOTETEXT] => 
            [EMAIL] => example.123@gmail.com
            [FIRSTNAME] => Andrew 
            [LASTNAME] => Mcmillan
            [MIDDLENAME] => Vann
            [SALUTATION] => 
            [SUFFIX] => 
            [COUNTRYCODE] => US
            [STATE] => NY
            [CITY] => new York
            [STREET] => 90 Northwest Boulevard
            [ZIP] => 10001
            [PHONENUM] => 201-938-9322
            [SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE] => US
            [SHIPTOSTATE] => NY
            [SHIPTOCITY] => new York
            [SHIPTOSTREET] => 90 Northwest Boulevard
            [SHIPTOZIP] => 10001
            [SHIPTOPHONENUM] => 201-938-9322
            [SHIPTOSTREET2] => Jersey City
            [STREET2] => Jersey City
            [SHIPTONAME] => Andrew  Vann Mcmillan
            [ADDROVERRIDE] => 1
            [METHOD] => SetExpressCheckout
            [VERSION] => 72.0
            [USER] => ****
            [PWD] => ****
            [SIGNATURE] => ****
            [BUTTONSOURCE] => Magento_Cart_Community
        )

    [response] => Array
        (
            [HTTP/1.1 200 OK
        Date: Wed, 20 Jan 2016 10:02:35 GMT
        Server: Apache
        X-PAYPAL-OPERATION-NAME: SetExpressCheckout
        X-PAYPAL-API-RC: 
        Connection: close
        Content-Length: 137
        Paypal-Debug-Id: bae7e9057d95a
        Set-Cookie: X-PP-SILOVER] => name=SANDBOX3.API.1&silo_version=880&app=appdispatcher_apit&TIME=995860310; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
        Set-Cookie: X-PP-SILOVER=; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT
        Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8

        TOKEN=EC-8PG38821N3655212U
                    [TIMESTAMP] => 2016-01-20T10:02:35Z
                    [CORRELATIONID] => bae7e9057d95a
                    [ACK] => Success
                    [VERSION] => 72.0
                    [BUILD] => 18308778
                )

            [__pid] => 28435

    )
```